# Flutter/Firebase type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to access data of specific documents from firebase
i used an external index to specify which document.
I'm using an aniaml modele that has strings and dynamic lists
and my firebase documents contain strings and lists of Strings
DatabaseService.dart

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hkScan/models/animal.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  DatabaseService({this.index});
  final index;
  final CollectionReference animalsCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('Animals');

  Animal _animalFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    try {
     return Animal(
      type: snapshot.documents[index].data['type"'] ?? '',
      feeding: snapshot.documents[index].data['feeding'] ?? '',
      slaughter: snapshot.documents[index].data['slaughter'] ?? '',
      breed: snapshot.documents[index].data['breed'] ?? '',
      cuts: snapshot.documents[index].data['cuts'] ?? '',
      grading: snapshot.documents[index].data['rating'] ?? '',
      image: snapshot.documents[index].data['image'] ?? '',
    );} catch(e){print(e.toString());return null;}
  }

  Stream<Animal> get animals {
    return animalsCollection.snapshots().map<Animal>(_animalFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Animal model:

```
class Animal {
  final String type;
  final String feeding;
  final List<dynamic> slaughter;
  final List<dynamic> breed;
  final List<dynamic> grading;
  final List<dynamic> cuts;
  final List<dynamic> image;
  Animal(
      {this.type,
      this.feeding,
      this.slaughter,
      this.breed,
      this.grading,
      this.cuts,
      this.image});
}
```

and this is how I pass the Streams from firebase to my app using StreamProvider

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hkScan/models/animal.dart';
import 'package:hkScan/services/database.dart';
import 'package:hkScan/widgets/animalsGrid.dart';
import 'package:hkScan/widgets/productCard.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'models/style.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int isSelected = 0;
  int dindex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Animal>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(index: dindex).animals,

          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xFF161D36),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
.
.
.
.
.
                Positioned(
                    left: 21,
                    top: 355,
                    height: 290,
                    width: 260,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final animal = Provider.of<Animal>(context);
                          return animal==null? Container():ProductCard(animal: animal,index: index,);
                        })),
.
.
.
.
.
```

ProductCard:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hkScan/models/animal.dart';

import 'package:hkScan/models/style.dart';

class ProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Animal animal;
  final index;
  ProductCard({this.animal, this.index});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: RoundedDiagonalPathClipper(),
      child: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(25)),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 25.0, sigmaY: 25.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 260.0,
                height: 71.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[900].withOpacity(0.2),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black38,
                      blurRadius:
                          15.0, // has the effect of softening the shadow
                      spreadRadius:
                          10.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
                      offset: Offset(
                        -13.0, // horizontal, move right 10
                        15.0, // vertical, move down 10
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          bottom: 0,
        ),
        Positioned(
            left: 20,
            bottom: 15,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(animal.type,
                    style: myStyle((20), FontWeight.w400, Color(0xFFD1E2F4))),
                Text(animal.grading[index],
                    style: myStyle((15), FontWeight.w400, Color(0xFFD1E2F4)))
              ],
            )),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

FireBase:
[Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeaLD.png)
Yet I keep getting this error:

```
I/flutter (11723): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

How do I fix this ?
thank you

Comment: You are trying to put a String value into a List<dynamic> variable. If you can tell which line the exception is referring to, we can tell you what to do. Without the line, it's too much work.

Comment: post a pic of complete db

Comment: I'm only trying ti access two fields (type and grading) for the moment, and the exception did not specify the line, I tried changing animal model field types(most precisely changed grading from List<dynamic> to List<String>  and the error message changed to this
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
I Can't assert grading as String because in my code it is indexed, and so is the case in firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
 slaughter: snapshot.documents[index].data['slaughter'] ?? '',
      breed: snapshot.documents[index].data['breed'] ?? '',
      cuts: snapshot.documents[index].data['cuts'] ?? '',
      grading: snapshot.documents[index].data['rating'] ?? '',
      image: snapshot.documents[index].data['image'] ?? '',
```

into this:

```
 slaughter: snapshot.documents[index].data['slaughter'] ?? [],
      breed: snapshot.documents[index].data['breed'] ?? [],
      cuts: snapshot.documents[index].data['cuts'] ?? [],
      grading: snapshot.documents[index].data['grading'] ?? [],
      image: snapshot.documents[index].data['image'] ?? [],
```

Since all those variables are of type `List<dynamic>` then assign empty list instead of empty string.

Comment: not sure if this worked, because i'm receiving a different error now:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
The relevant error-causing widget was
ProductCard
can you help me with this please?

Comment: inside the `animalFromSnapshot` do `print(snapshot.documents[index].data['slaughter'])`

Comment: OK i got this!
I/flutter (11723): [Halal, gaz]

Comment: check the edit in the answer, in your database you have a list called `grading` and not `rating`